# Selecting parent records when child mathes criteria

Tags: mysql, sybase, pervasive, faircom-db-sql

I am trying to limit returned results of users to results that are "recent" but where users have a parent, I also need to return the parent.

```
CREATE TABLE `users`  (
  `id` int(0) NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(0) NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
CREATE TABLE `times` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `users`(`id`, `parent_id`, `name`) VALUES (1, NULL, 'Alan');
INSERT INTO `users`(`id`, `parent_id`, `name`) VALUES (2, 1, 'John');
INSERT INTO `users`(`id`, `parent_id`, `name`) VALUES (3, NULL, 'Jerry');
INSERT INTO `users`(`id`, `parent_id`, `name`) VALUES (4, NULL, 'Bill');
INSERT INTO `users`(`id`, `parent_id`, `name`) VALUES (5, 1, 'Carl');

INSERT INTO `times`(`id`, `time`) VALUES (2, '2019-01-01 14:40:38');
INSERT INTO `times`(`id`, `time`) VALUES (4, '2019-01-01 14:40:38');
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/91db19

In this case I would want to return Alan, John and Bill, but not Jerry because Jerry doesn't have a record in the `times` table, nor is he a parent of someone with a record. I am on the fence about what to do with Carl, I don't mind getting the results for him, but I don't need them.

I am filtering tens of thousands of users with hundreds of thousands of `times` records, so performance is important. In general I have about 3000 unique id's coming from `times` that could be either an `id`, or a `parent_id`.

The above is a stripped down example of what I am trying to do, the full one includes more joins  and case statements, but in general the above example should be what we work with, but here is a sample of the query I am using (full query is nearly 100 lines):

```
SELECT id                                   AS reference_id, 
       CASE WHEN (id != parent_id)
       THEN
       parent_id
       ELSE null END                                    AS parent_id, 
       parent_id                                          AS family_id, 
       Rtrim(last_name)                                 AS last_name, 
       Rtrim(first_name)                                AS first_name, 
       Rtrim(email)                                     AS email, 
       missedappt                                     AS appointment_missed, 
       appttotal                                      AS appointment_total, 
       To_char(birth_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00')       AS birthday, 
       To_char(first_visit_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00') AS first_visit, 
       billing_0_30
FROM   users AS p
      RIGHT JOIN(
                SELECT p.id, 
                       s.parentid, 
                       Count(p.id) AS appttotal, 
                       missedappt, 
                        billing0to30                                        AS billing_0_30
                FROM   times AS p 
                       JOIN (SELECT missedappt, parent_id, id                                     
                             FROM   users) AS s 
                         ON p.id = s.id 
                       LEFT JOIN (SELECT parent_id, billing0to30
                                  FROM   aging) AS aging 
                              ON aging.parent_id = p.id 
                WHERE  p.apptdate > To_char(Timestampadd(sql_tsi_year, -1, Now()), 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
                GROUP  BY p.id, 
                          s.parent_id, 
                          missedappt, 
                          billing0to30
                ) AS recent ON recent.patid = p.patient_id
```

This example is for a Faircom C-Tree database, but I also need to implement a similar solution in Sybase, MySql, and Pervasive, so just trying to understand what I should do for best performance.

Essentially what I need to do is somehow get the `RIGHT JOIN` to also include the users parent.

Comment: I'd start by stripping down your query to match your stripped-down tables, throw in an example result set of what you're looking for, and while you're at it how about your database versions (eg, MySQL 5.6 does not suport CTES but MySQL 8+ does) and in the case of 'sybase' => which Sybase RDBMS product (ASE? SQLAnywhere? IQ? ADS?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTES:

- based on your fiddle config I'm assuming you're using MySQL 5.6 and thus don't have support for Common Table Expressions (CTE)
- I'm assuming each name (child or parent) is to be presented as separate records in the final result set

We want to limit the number of times we have to join the `times` and `users` tables (a CTE would make this a bit easier to code/read).

The main query (times -> users(u1) -> users(u2)) will give us child and parent names in separate columns so we'll use a 2-row dynamic table plus a `case` statement to to pivot the columns into their own rows (NOTE: I don't work with MySQL and didn't have time to research if there's a `pivot` capability in MySQL 5.6)

```
-- we'll let 'distinct' filter out any duplicates (eg, 2 'children' have same 'parent')

select distinct 
       final.name

from

    -- cartesian product of 'allnames' and 'pass' will give us
    -- duplicate lines of id/parent_id/child_name/parent_name so 
    -- we'll use a 'case' statement to determine which name to display

    (select case when pass.pass_no = 1 
                 then allnames.child_name 
                 else allnames.parent_name 
            end as name

     from 

         -- times join users left join users; gives us pairs of
         -- child_name/parent_name or child_name/NULL

         (select u1.id,u1.parent_id,u1.name as child_name,u2.name as parent_name
          from   times t
          join   users u1
          on     u1.id = t.id

          left
          join   users u2
          on     u2.id = u1.parent_id) allnames

          join

          -- poor man's pivot code:
          -- 2-row dynamic table; no join clause w/ allnames will give us a
          -- cartesian product; the 'case' statement will determine which
          -- name (child vs parent) to display

          (select 1 as pass_no
           union
           select 2) pass

    ) final

-- eliminate 'NULL' as a name in our final result set
where final.name is not NULL

order by 1
```

Result set:

```
name
==============
Alan
Bill
John
```

[MySQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/91db19/52)